# AuthorizationRuleProvider rule and Domain group name with space in it

Tags: security, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

I have a domain group with space in it, it does not work. The only related thing I find on google is this unanswered question

http://webclientguidance.codeplex.com/discussions/9242

```
<rules>
    <add name="User" expression="R:MyDomain\MyApp Users" />
</rules>
```

I am getting this exception :

> Found token "end of file" when expecting word at position 17.

Comment: Zero answers on SO, thats a pretty good indicator that we are using obsolete software :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was painful simple

```
<add name="User" expression="R:&quot;MyDomain\MyApp Users&quot;" />
```